# Sort a Realm list and persist the result

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a `Realm` model that contains a list of products:

```
class StorageArea: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let products = List<Product>()
}
```

How can I sort the products alphabetically and persist the result in Realm? I cannot find any mutable method on the List class to reorder the elements and persist the ordered result.

I have a `TableViewController` showing all the products. The user can move products in the `tableView`, quit the app and restart the app: the ordered list of products is persisted. I am using List.move(from, to) for that.

Now I would like to add an option to sort the products alphabetically or by date. What would you recommend to modify the products list and save it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that by retrieving first a sorted list of products, then remove all items from the list and re-add them all in the new order.

```
realm.write {
    let storageArea = …
    let sortedProducts = Array(storageArea.products.sorted("name"))
    storageArea.products.removeAll()
    storageArea.products.appendContentsOf(sortedProducts)
}
```

Comment: How does this reflect in the underlying layer? Does it also remove the items from the realm itself and then saves them again, or is it just locally in the list? If the former then that's super inefficient...

Comment: @Michal: No, it just removes the references from the list and re-adds them. The persisted products are not affected by that.

Comment: If I use the sorted("name") method (and not sort method like you wrote), sortedProducts is empty after the removeAll() call, so the new sorted list is always empty. Any tip?

Comment: I guess it's because the Results is an auto-updating container type. So I must convert it to an array first...

Comment: @franswa: Sure, you're right the method name is `sorted` and yes, I forgot the array constructor, which you can use to pull accessors for all objects matched by the query. Otherwise exactly what you describe happens: the `Results` underlying query is updated and has no matches anymore.